# Drawing a rectangle in an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to implement face detection using Google Mobile Vision in an Android app. In the app, I have an Imageview and a button with text, "Process".

When the button is clicked, the code connects with Google's Vision API and detects the face. After detecting the face, I am trying to draw a rectangle around the face. For that purpose I am using "Canvas" available in Android.

The error (not exactly) is I am unable to see the rectangle around the face. Here is the code in my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.startertutorials.googlefacedetect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Landmark;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button btnProcess;

    Bitmap myBitmap;
    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        btnProcess = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnProcess);

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.me);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), myBitmap.getConfig());
        canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

        btnProcess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                        .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                        .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
                        .build();

                if (!faceDetector.isOperational()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Face Detector Setup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
                SparseArray<Face> sparseArray = faceDetector.detect(frame);
                for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++) {
                    Face face = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
                    detectLandmarks(face);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void detectLandmarks(Face face) {
        float height = face.getHeight();
        float width = face.getWidth();
        PointF p = face.getPosition();
        float cx = p.x;
        float cy = p.y;
        drawOnImageView(cx, cy, height, width);
        /*
        for(Landmark landmark:face.getLandmarks())
        {
            int cx = (int)landmark.getPosition().x;
            int cy = (int)landmark.getPosition().y;

            drawOnImageView(landmark.getType(),cx,cy);
        }
        */
    }

    private void drawOnImageView(float cx, float cy, float height, float width) {
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, myPaint);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        Log.d("Success", "Face detected successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The output after I click the "Process" button in the app is as follows:

[image]

In the logcat of Android studio, I can see the message "Face detected successfully". So, I am assuming that all my code is running. But I am unable to see the rectangle.

**Please help me with displaying a rectangle first. Later I will adjust it to display around the face.**

Answer (score -1):

You have to extend the Detector class:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/Detector

Defining your RectangleDetector class. The code to detect rectangles would be implemented by overriding the detect() method. You'd need to implement this yourself, since there isn't already code for detecting rectangles in mobile vision.

When you have this, you'd be able to use it with CameraSource and other parts of the mobile vision API.

Comment: I want to display a normal rectangle on top of the Imageview (containing Federer's image). I don't want to detect rectangles.